# package compatability between Scala 2.10 and 2.11

Tags: scala

Is it possible to include 2.10 packages in 2.11 programs, and vis versa? 
Are there any special corner cases I should watch out for?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Major versions are not binary compatible with each other. So for any Scala versions `2.x.y` and `2.w.z`, where `x != w`, they will not be compatible. All libraries must be compiled against the same major version, however minor version differences are okay.

Comment: It's possible to use 2.10 libs (n-1) in 2.11 (n) app (as Java 7 lib can be used in Java 8 app).

Comment: @__0 Even if that's recommanded that's *possible*, you can easily find such case on github

Comment: You might be able to compile a 2.10 library with a 2.11 library where they are both source compatible, but you'll most certainly hit runtime errors that you can't overcome because of binary compatibility.